# Meteor fetch on client undefined outside of helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, simple-schema

I am trying to fetch an entry in a collection with:

*client/views/home.js*:

```
criticalCrewNumber = ConfigValues.find({
  name: 'criticalCrewNumber'
}).fetch()[0].value;
```

But I'm getting error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

If I run the code in the browser console, the desired value is returned as a string.

I have tried various things, e.g. using `findOne`; placing the code elsewhere in the app; using iron-router `waitOn` for the subscription to come, etc. Every attempt so far has failed as I end up with `undefined`.

Here's how the collection is defined, published and subscribed to:

*lib/config/admin_config.js*:

```
ConfigValues = new Mongo.Collection("configValues");

ConfigValues.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Name",
    max: 200
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
    label: "Value",
    max: 200
  }
}));
```

*both/collections/eventsCollection.js*:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('events');
  Meteor.subscribe('config');
};
```

*server/lib/collections.js*

```
Meteor.publish('events', function () {
        return Events.find();
    });

Meteor.publish('config', function () {
        return ConfigValues.find();
    });
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: This is a really common issue with meteor. Can you say more about where the find is being called? For example is it inside onCreated, or is it just at the file scope?

Comment: At the moment of calling `find`, there is no data in Minimongo - local copy of database - that's why `.find(...).fetch()` returns empty array. When you run this line in console, subscription is ready and data is already available.

Comment: What do the publish functions look like?

Comment: Thanks all. I added publish function to my question. @RadosławM – How should I deal with this? Should I wrap the code in some subscription waiting code, like a reactive var type thing?

Comment: If that suits your needs, yes - it's one of many options.

Comment: @RadosławM Can you specify what you would do? I'm not sure what wrapping code I should use there.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) (and [`Meteor.subscribe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) callbacks):

```
criticalCrewNumber = new ReactiveVar();

Meteor.subscribe('config', {
    onReady: function () {
        var config = ConfigValues.findOne({name: 'criticalCrewNumber'});
        if (config) {
            criticalCrewNumber.set(config.value);
        } else {
            console.error('No config value.');
        }
    },

    onStop: function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
});
```